# biggest possible number for sort -n

Tags: sort

How to determine the "biggest number" so that sort -n will always put it at the end?  I'm thinking of something along `Inf` in some languages but I'm not sure if anything like this exists for sort.

---

The background is that I'm sorting list of potentially non-existent paths by age so that

- existent go first, from newest to oldest,
- non-existent go last.

I'm using decoration approach and trying to put penalty on those unborns:

```bsh
INFINITY=99999999999999   # ...close enough, right?

age_of() {
    if [ -e $1 ];
    then
        local ctime=$(stat -c %Z "$1" 2>/dev/null)
        local now=$(date +%s)
        echo $(($now - $ctime))
    else
        echo $INFINITY
    fi
}

cat - \
  | while read path;
    do
        echo "$(age_of $path) $path"
    done \
      | sort -n \
      | cut -d\  -f 2-
```

but obviously the comment is pretty naive; it's just a matter of time when even 99999999999999 will *not* be close enough. ;)

So is there a better value for INFINITY?

Comment: Do you need it to work on all platforms or just on yours?

Comment: @ALiX Since it's rather theoretical question I'd prefer solution on all platforms, or say, within some reasonable standard like POSIX.  (I'll be using part of that code on my Fedora box but I'm not planning on living that long so I'm OK with current value there ;)).

Comment: I don't think that the -n flag necessarily has a limit. It could be implemented without resorting to actually converting to a number (so there wouldn't e a largest number). If you output something non-numerice, then all the sort versions I have seen will put the non-numerics last.

Comment: @ALiX I'm not really looking for limit since that will make the behavior undefined if `age_of` returned the same number.  I'm rather looking for something that will *always be after all numbers* ... if it makes sense.

Comment: Right. So for example if INFINITY=z, then all the non-existent will come last when using sort -n. Or do you mean that you have to have a numeric value there?

Comment: @ALiX no, I mean what you mean by "z". Problem is that all non-numerals I've tried come as zero

Comment: `sort -g` (a GNUism, but then you're using GNU stat) recognises `"inf"`. `perl -lne '$age = -M; $age = "inf" unless defined $age; print "$age $_"' | sort -g`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a POSIX solution, but GNU sort offers the `-g` option which supports a wider range of number specifications including infinity. From http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html -

```
‘-g’
‘--general-numeric-sort’
‘--sort=general-numeric’

Sort numerically, converting a prefix of each line to a long double-precision
floating point number. See Floating point. Do not report overflow, underflow, or
conversion errors. Use the following collating sequence:

    Lines that do not start with numbers (all considered to be equal).
    NaNs (“Not a Number” values, in IEEE floating point arithmetic) in a
      consistent but machine-dependent order.
    Minus infinity.
    Finite numbers in ascending numeric order (with -0 and +0 equal).
    Plus infinity. 

Use this option only if there is no alternative; it is much slower than
--numeric-sort (-n) and it can lose information when converting to floating
point.
```

From my own tests it seems that any line beginning with `Inf` (any combination of upper/lower case) will appear after any numbers.

Failing that I don't think there are any character sequences that are reliably sorted after numbers using `sort -n`. GNU sort seems to treat all other sequences first as zero, placing the after negative numbers but before positive ones. What you could do, if it is timestamps that are being sorted, is to use the maximum value for a 64 bit timestamp plus one:

```
 9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

This is a few more digits than you started out with!

Comment: *GNU sort seems to put all other sequences first.* From my tests (coreutils-8.21-21.fc20.x86_64), it actually seems that `sort -g` does that, e.g. (I'm using `:` for brevity here) `"a:b:-inf:-10:0:10:inf"`, while `sort -n` regards all NaN's zero so that they end up *in the middle*, e.g. `"-10:a:b:-inf:inf:0:10"`

Comment: That said, your great answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Alois, good point I never thought to try negative numbers.

Comment: I also had the maximum timestamp approach in mind, but then I wonder if there's a command that can give me *that* number regardless of architecture (64bit or 32bit etc.)

Comment: @Alois, I don't think so. I don't think the number of bits used for a timestamp is dependent on architecture - 32 machines can still use 64 bit timestamps AFAIK. Nor am I aware of any command that will tell you the size of the underlying `time_t` type. You are safe to assume that it won't be any larger than 64 bits though (almost certainly since 64 bit timestamps are safe for 200+ billion years). The only use for larger ones is to include fractions of seconds (as fixed point) which doesn't affect the maximum.

Comment: I think the perfect value should the lower of either maximum of what sort can handle or maximum timestamp.  I mean, if I assume 64bit max, how will sort handle that on 32bit?  It makes sense that in most cases they would be the same, i.e. maximum int; shouldn't that be somewhere under /sys?

Comment: @Alois, I don't think there is a maximum value that `sort` can handle. A prudent implementation would avoid converting the string to a number internally so length wouldn't be a problem. You can still use a similar approach as for a pure lexical comparison to compare numbers - this would be the more robust than a conversion. You would only then be limited in extreme cases, perhaps where a number has `INT_MAX` digits (if the system hasn't already run out of memory).